# Can I squash together multiple commits and keep the message from the last one?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Sometimes I `git rebase -i master` and have this situation:

```
pick cc1ed9d First commit
pick 9d4090c Main commit with detailed message
pick fca9df4 WIP afterthought commit with bad message
```

By changing the last line's `pick` to `fixup`, I squash it into the main commit, and the new, combined commit uses the main commit's nice message.

But sometimes the order is different:

```
pick cc1ed9d First commit
pick fca9df4 WIP preliminary commit with failing test
pick 9d4090c Main commit with detailed message
```

Here I'd like to squash together the last two commits but keep the message from the last one.

I can do this with laborious copy and paste, but is there a simple way?

Comment: Change `pick` to `squash` instead of `fixup`, then Git proposes a commit message that concatenates all the squashed ones' messages and lets you edit that to whatever you want to keep, which at least avoids "laborious copy and paste".

Comment: Adding a bit of clarity to @underscore_d, that this squash would be on the 9d4090c in the 2nd example rather than on fca9df4 as you proposed on the first example. Then you can just control+k to cut through lines like a knife in hot butter (joke assumes you are using nano as your text editor).

Comment: @underscore_d Oh dang, I've done that before but forgot how it worked.  Make an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slightly change what you have been doing. If you change `pick` (a.k.a. `p`) to `squash` (`s`) instead of `fixup` (`f`), then Git will combine the commits' changes in the same way, but instead of automatically retaining the 1st commit's message will bring up your text editor. Therein will be a proposed commit message, which concatenates the messages of all the consecutively squashed commits, from which you can edit down to whatever you want to keep.

This does not 100% automatically retain only the message of the last commit, to be fair, but it sure avoids the mentioned "laborious copy and paste"!

Think of `fixup` as `squash` without the extra step of editing the message, basically, so by changing from `fixup` to `squash` you get the full squashing experience (lol).

Answer (score 2):

Interactive rebase is intended to present a lot of options, if you already know exactly what you want to do, just do it:

```
git reset --soft @~2; git commit -C @{1}
```

with a clean index to squash the last two commits together keeping the tip commit's message.

Comment: Cool! It seems to work, of course. What if we wanted to do this over more than 2 commits, and/or keeping a different one's method? Is this example generalisable?

Comment: @underscore_d Yes you can with `git rebase -x`. I gave a very practical example in [this thread on how to reformat a whole branch](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/r2kpdm/comment/hm6af6x/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).